# getIntent() wrote in red

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to pass string from main activity to another class extends from services. I send it like this from onCreate method at main:

```
Intent phoneintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmServic.class);
String phoneN = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
phoneintent.putExtra("PhoneNumber",phoneN );
startActivity(phoneintent);
```

and receive it inside onStartCommand method like this:

```
String phone = getIntent().getExtras().getString("PhoneNumber");
```

but it give me getIntent() in red and it cannot solve it

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent phoneintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmServic.class);
String phoneN = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
phoneintent.putExtra("PhoneNumber",phoneN );
startService(phoneintent);// If its a Service
```

And Retrieve in Service as

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

     String phoneNumber= intent.getStringExtra("PhoneNumber");
     ...........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use bundle in 1st Activity

`Bundle bundle=new Bundle();`
`bundle.putString("key",phone);`
`Intent intent=new Intent(?.this,?.class);`
`intent.putExtras(bundle);`
`startActivity(intent);`

//2nd Screen

`Bundle bundle=new Bundle();

if(bundle!=null){
String boom=bundle.getString("key");
}`

//stored the value
//do whatever