# Why getIntent() error red line in my code?

Tags: android, parcelable

i want to send parcelable data from MainActivity to LocationService. but when i want to retrive data on LocationService and type this code line.  But ended up with error red line.

i've tried this [getIntent() wrote in red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983535/getintent-wrote-in-red), but i want to use the object on other method, and alos the object become null.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

[image]

i hope you guys can help and maybe have others suggestion. thank you

Comment: If this method is in service then use Intent intent = getApplicationContext().getIntent();

Comment: Probably because `#getIntent()` is method of `Activity` . And this is not an `Activity` class.

Comment: i've tried it. it's doesn't work too. @NickBapu

Comment: so, how i can send data from activity to service? @ADM

Comment: to send data from activity to service you can implement interface. Let me modify my answer.

Comment: OK! I understand probably you are using LocationService extends Service. You can also use IntentService for that purpose.

Comment: so LocationService extends IntentService? @NickBapu

Comment: Yes there is easy way to deal data with intent using IntentService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass data using intent

```
Intent serviceIntent= new Intent(Activity_Namethis,Service_Name.class);
serviceIntent.intent.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY, YOUR_OBJECT);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Retrieve data From Service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
   YOUR_CLASS _yourClassObject = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_KEY);

   return "RETURN_FLAG";
}
```

you can also Bundle all your data and add that t`enter code here`o your intent

Answer (score 0):

As You are trying to call getIntent from service, So its not the method of service class, you need to have a reference of Activity class before calling it like

```
activity.getIntent()
```

Edited:

Now to send data from activity to service you can implement an interface

Declare an interface

```
 public interface MyIntentListener {
    public void call();
 }
```

Now implement this interface in your service like

```
 class yourService extends ... implements MyIntentListener {

     // other stuff
     @override
     public void call() {
     }
 }
```

Now in Activity where you are initializing the service, you must have its reference, so you can call anywhere in activity

```
 service.call()
```

Comment: you can pass Intent in call() method, I forgot to add that, according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_INFO);`
you do not need to create intent variable the sore 'getIntent()' into that..just get it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IntentService for this kind of work:

```
public class LocationService extends IntentService {
    public LocationService() {
        super("LocationService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //Get data from intent here.
    }
}
```

To start and use IntentService:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, LocationService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

from activity. And you can pass any kind of your data into serviceIntent object.